# Integer variable optimization - decreasing execution time

Tags: optimization, mixed-integer-programming, ampl

I have a variable declared as follows in AMPL:

```
var i {j in UNIT, t in PERIOD}
integer <= 3; 

# therefore, an integer variable is declared that can take values ...,-1,0,1,2,3
```

Below are the two constraints where this integer variable is used.

\begin{align}c(j,t) &\le E(j,t)\cdot i(j,t)\\d(j,t)&\le F(j,t)\cdot i(j,t)\end{align}

The capital letters denote parameters and small letters are variables. There is a need to optimize the integer variable this way for later use in the formulation. Is there a way I can reformulate the constraints or formulate the variable condition declaration as constraint to make the execution time of the program faster?

Comment: Are you sure your declaration precludes negative integer values? I'm not an AMPL user, but that looks rather suspicious to me.

Comment: You are correct, I edited that part.

Comment: Can you clarify what the problem is with the current formulation? These constraints seem pretty straightforward -- is there something tricky here that you're trying to accomplish?

Comment: For some reason, the code executes slowly, I was wondering if there is a way I can reformulate that might make the execution faster.